# Mysql Update, Select Replace specified character in a long string

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

I am not sure how to approach I could do some tests but I am asking just to be on the safe side and get some suggestions.

I have a table column with lots of data E.G:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. @ Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`

The above is just a placeholder each row will have different data string, what I need to do is Update all the rows by removing the @ sign from them I have found some examples like:

`UPDATE table SET string = REPLACE(string, '@', '')` But not sure if this the query will update just what is found or will replace my entire string for the @ sign that means I loose all my data and will @ sign only on them. Can anyone advise if this will just replace the @ and leave the rest intact?

Answer (score 0):

The query: `UPDATE table SET string = REPLACE(string, '@', '')`

For string such as: `The quick brown fox jumps over @ the lazy dog`

Will actually just replace the `@` sign and leave everything else intact so the my column after the query will contain `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`